# msg.sender 'spoofing' when function is public or external

Tags: security, addresses, accounts

I have a Smart contract where I want only the onwer to call a specific function, for example:

```
function getInfo() view public onlyOwner() returns (address) {
  return msg.sender;
}
.....
modifier onlyOwner ()  {
  require ( msg.sender== my_owner);
}
```

I can build a web3 call slaiming to be (calling from) any address, in this case the owner of the contract, for example:

```
web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

......
if(directAccessMode)
    web3.eth.defaultAccount =   '0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111';
......
```

and be able to geth the required information without any check from EVM that I am really the 'owner' of the address I am claiming to be even avoiding using the address' access details.

I am aware that smart contract data is public nevertheless I do not understnad why there is no control on caller's address validity.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your function is executing on-chain, the caller cannot set `msg.sender` to whatever they want. `msg.sender` will always be the user account or the contract that is calling your contract function. It can never be something like 0x11111111...

When your function is executing off-chain (e.g. a `view` function being called from web3), the caller can set `msg.sender` to whatever they want. This is not a security risk, because:

1. A function that executes off-chain cannot change the contract state, perform on-chain transactions or do anything else on-chain. It can never have any effect on anyone else's function calls.
2. All data stored on-chain is publicly readable. Even if there isn't a view function to read it, you can still read any contract state variable using `web3.eth.getStorageAt(...)`.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware that is not a security risk nevertheless if I want to track callers of some of my functions, I would be forced to impose a on-chain function with therefore correlated costs. Even logging of events within a node would not be able to track the caller.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is protection from someone attempting to spoof your owner address. This is because although msg.sender may be modified for the tx, it will not succeed b/c the tx must be signed with the private key of the actual account, which the spoofer does not possess.